# How to centre align a heading with existing CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a css template  for a search bar which i am using. I need to add a heading just above and below the search bar , however as i add it , the heading is not centre aligning with my code nor the margin styling is working for me. Can anybody tell me what should be the css to align it in centre of the page , just above the search bar. If i add alignment, the search bar alignment is disturbed. Here is the css for search bar :

```
.heading{
 font-family: Fondamento;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 26.4px;
 padding: 0.75em;
 position: relative;
}

* {
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
:root {
    font-size: calc(16px + (24 - 16)*(100vw - 320px)/(1920 - 320));
}
body, button, input {
    font: 1em Hind, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
body, input {
    color: #171717;
}
body, .search-bar {
    display: flex;
}
body {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    height: 100vh;
}
.search-bar input,
.search-btn,
.search-btn:before,
.search-btn:after {
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
.search-bar input,
.search-btn {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
}
.search-bar input:invalid:not(:focus),
.search-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search-bar,
.search-bar input:focus,
.search-bar input:valid  {
    width: 100%;
}
.search-bar input:focus,
.search-bar input:not(:focus) + .search-btn:focus {
    outline: transparent;
}
.search-bar {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.5em;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 30em;
}
.search-bar input {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.4em #171717 inset;
    padding: 0.75em;
    transform: translate(0.5em,0.5em) scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.search-bar input::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.search-bar input:focus,
.search-bar input:valid {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.375em 0 0 0.375em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em #d9d9d9 inset;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.search-btn {
    background: #171717;
    border-radius: 0 0.75em 0.75em 0 / 0 1.5em 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0.75em;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(0.25em,0.25em) rotate(45deg) scale(0.25,0.125);
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.search-btn:before,
.search-btn:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.search-btn:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em #f1f1f1 inset;
    top: 0.75em;
    left: 0.75em;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
}
.search-btn:after {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
    top: 51%;
    left: 51%;
    width: 0.75em;
    height: 0.25em;
    transform: translate(0.2em,0) rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.search-btn span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}

/* Active state */
.search-bar input:focus + .search-btn,
.search-bar input:valid + .search-btn {
    background: #2762f3;
    border-radius: 0 0.375em 0.375em 0;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.search-bar input:focus + .search-btn:before,
.search-bar input:focus + .search-btn:after,
.search-bar input:valid + .search-btn:before,
.search-bar input:valid + .search-btn:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.search-bar input:focus + .search-btn:hover,
.search-bar input:valid + .search-btn:hover,
.search-bar input:valid:not(:focus) + .search-btn:focus {
    background: #0c48db;
}
.search-bar input:focus + .search-btn:active,
.search-bar input:valid + .search-btn:active {
    transform: translateY(1px);
}

@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body, input {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    body {
        background: #171717;
    }
    .search-bar input {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.4em #f1f1f1 inset;
    }
    .search-bar input:focus,
    .search-bar input:valid {
        background: #3d3d3d;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em #3d3d3d inset;
    }
    .search-btn {
        background: #f1f1f1;
    }
}
```

i need to change the ".heading" css.

HTML Code :

```
<body>
<h1 class = "heading">WikiMedia</h1>
  <form action="/search" method="post" class="search-bar">
    <input type="search" name="text" pattern=".*\S.*" required>
    <button class="search-btn" type="submit">
        <span>Search</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello, can you please provide your html as well? I also recommend you insert a snippet (try hitting `ctrl+m` as you are editing your question), and insert your code into the snippet so that we can all run your code, and see the issue.

Comment: Hey buddy, It's hard to help without the HTML code, maybe you can give us the HTML snippet or host your work on GitHub pages and share the link so we can see the problem and help you.

images to show the desired result and another image to show the problem is a huge help too.

Comment: Please note that external link as requested above is not enough - you must include the code in the question itself. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all the relevant code including the HTML so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help.

Comment: Hi all , i have updated the code above with HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

without the HTML code its not possible to give you a solution but   i have some suggestions.

- put the heading in a seperate `div` and then change its `display:flex`. then add `justify-content:center` and `align-items:center`.

this should work.